# Safari leaves a space on the right side with 100% width grid

Tags: css, safari, responsive-design, grid, sass

I'm trying to make my own grid which does fit al my needs but I can't find a way to make it the full width at Safari (Mac & iOS). It works nicely in other browsers (Chrome, Firefox, IE10) but in Safari and Safari mobile it leaves a space on the right side.

Are there any solutions for this? I'm a pixel perfectionist so this frustrates me so much.

Image preview:

[image]

Demo: http://codepen.io/PatrickVerwoerd/pen/wImcu

Comment: what happens if you move your `display:table` from the `:before` and `:after` to just `.group` - http://codepen.io/anon/pen/LIpjE (I don't have safari to test)

Comment: Nothing happens in Safari

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a sub-pixel rounding error. It's common in any fluid layout, but becomes most obvious when you do the same math over and over (12 equal columns in a row). When you have a fluid layout, there are times when your container (as measured in pixels) doesn't divide evenly by the % you set. Say the viewport is `966px` wide, and your columns are `10%`. That means each column should be `96.6px` wide. Browsers just don't know what to do with that partial pixel. If you resize your container, you'll see that the layout *jumps* now and then, and lines up exactly right when the container is evenly divisible.

It's an [old problem](http://ejohn.org/blog/sub-pixel-problems-in-css/), and browsers have mostly been getting better at handling it. IE used to round up, which caused even worse layout problems. Now, most browsers are smarter about it, but Safari still rounds down.

There's no way to fix the problem entirely. *There are no pixel-exact, fluid, floated layouts,* but there are several work-arounds. I start with the simplest, and work my way through the list:

1. When possible, avoid repetitive percentages. Any one element will only ever round down a partial pixel, meaning you never have more than `1px` error at a time. If you don't stack the errors, they are easier to hide.
2. Float the last item in a row to the right. That moves the rounding error in-between columns, where it is generally less noticeable.
3. If you really can't minimize or hide the errors, in a gallery-style layout for example, try Jon Albin Wilkins' [float isolation method](http://www.palantir.net/blog/responsive-design-s-dirty-little-secret). It's a bulky approach, so I don't recommend it everywhere, but it can be real helpful in some cases. Layout systems like [Susy](http://susy.oddbird.net) and [Singularity](http://singularity.gs) will also give you that as an option.

With a combination of those techniques, you can keep all your rounding errors to a single pixel. If your designs can't handle a single pixel rounding error, you shouldn't use fluid  floats, or you should maybe consider the [Dao](http://alistapart.com/article/dao/). :)

Comment: Just ran some tests. Last I knew, all webkit browsers and Opera rounded down. Looks to me like Chrome and Opera have fixed that. Firefox was already handling things pretty well, and based on your image IE10 must be fixed as well. Glad to see Safari has become the last holdout!

Comment: Thnx for your help Eric. I chose the second solution: http://codepen.io/PatrickVerwoerd/pen/hopwz

Works like a charm, even in IE8. 
12 Columns are almost never used so this solution is plausible if you ask me.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that SCSS in the CodePen is calculating the margin and width to a certain decimal level.

```
/* Actual Math */
53px / 966px * 100 // = 5.486542443%

/* Codepen Math */
53px / 966px * 100 // = 5.48654%
```

As you can see the remaining decimals are ignored and therefore your grid is technically not adding up to 100% and therefore a space at the end.

It seems the other browsers are compensating for that by assuming you mean to extend the full 100% whereas Safari is being more accurate (whether that's the correct appraoch will depend on what you're trying to achieve).

Comment: Good note but unfortunately that's not the solution.
I just tried it with a 10column grid (10% width, no margin) but the same problem: http://codepen.io/PatrickVerwoerd/pen/dmnJD

Comment: That's really strange, when I tried my solution it worked a treat but you are right with your 10% example.

Comment: It seems to still be as a result of the rounding that Safari is applying to the elements. If you change your max-width to 960/970/980 then it will work, but as soon as you include 966/965/967 it will leave the additional background.  Not a solution for you, but at least a implementation around the issue.